# Using MySQL Workbench causes errors on Galera Cluster

Tags: mysql-workbench, galera

I have a 5 cluster MariaDB/Galera cluster running in production environment. 
I also have a monitor which checks every 20 seconds for cluster size changes. One of our other engineers has been running queries using MySQL Workbench, and when that application is running, I start seeing alerts coming from my monitor where cluster size is 1. It does recover in a few seconds back to the correct size of 5, however it's disconcerting that this client app is causing issues on the cluster. I've requested everyone on our team to not use this app... however I wonder if anyone else has seen this, or knows what it is doing to the cluster.

Comment: So, you believe an application that sends standard SQL commands is guilty of irritating your cluster? Have you tried sending the same queries from any other client app? Is there a particular query that shows this odd behavior? And btw. MySQL Workbench is a **MySQL** tool.

Comment: I observed this when running the "server monitor" feature of MySQL workbench - not even running a query. However, other engineers are running this remotely, so I'm not sure what queries they are running. However the python script that monitors the cluster size runs once per 20 seconds, and is silent in alerts until someone uses workbench. When using HeidiSQL or other tool, this does not occur. It's very repeatable. We're running MariaDB.

Comment: What metric determines "cluster size"?

Comment: Check the query log to see what was sent to the server and try to repeat the odd behavior of your cluster by resending them. Maybe one of those is something that MariaDB/Galera have problems with. After all, MySQL Workbench is for **MySQL** servers.

Comment: For cluster size we execute "show status like 'wsrep_cluster_size'" and if it changes value up or down it gets reported. It can run for weeks w/o an error but when someone logs in with MySQL workbench it throws these errors. This is not a serious issue but worth noting.